# Bootstrap col-xs-12 as row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When using bootstraps grid system I often am confronted with the decision between shorter and neater code and probably correct but longer code.

Lets assume the following code

```
<div class="row some-class">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        content A
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        content B
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

It appears to me as if the following code has exactly the same result.

```
<div class="row some-class">
  <div class="col-xs-12">content A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">content B</div>
</div>
```

Is that so? And even if, is it good practice to use `col-xs-12` as some kind of a shortcut for a row/col-construct?

I need the wrapper `row` because `some-class` contains styling.

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong, in my opinion it's correct, both ways and I use `col-xs-*` only when I'm working with sites for desktop only

Comment: Why would you use the grid classes here at all? Simple `<div class="some-class"><div>content A</div><div>content B</div></div>` would give you the same result.

Comment: IMHO, they would be equivalent and, obviously, the second option is less verbose (i.e. better: faster, easier to maintain) - So, if you only plan to have one 'break-point' for your layout, then by all means use it.  The difference comes when you want to have more than one 'break-point' in your layout - ie you want to use the entire width for `xs` but for larger screens you want `lg` (or whatever) - the second option gives you one row to break A and B into columns as you see fit (2 and 10, 6 and 6, etc) -  the first option forces you to use rows even if the column width is not 12.